# ComboBox reverting to index 0 at seemingly random

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have an `array` of `ComboBoxes`, each with it's own `DataSource` which is set at the beginning and not messed with any further. Each `ComboBox` has some index (which is not 0) selected.

Now, I have a grid of `Panels` drawn on a `Form`. Each `Panel` is connected to it's own `ComboBox`. According to set rules, `ComboBox` can be drawn on the `Form`. Here are the rules:

On `mouseClick` connected-`ComboBox` is designated as selected-`ComboBox`. It was already drawn on `mouseEnter` event.

On `mouseEnter` selected-`ComboBox` is replaced with the connected-`ComboBox`.

On `mouseLeave` connected-`ComboBox` is replaced with selected-`ComboBox`.

Basically, it displays the last selected `ComboBox`, or the one you are currently hovering over.

When I started the program and started hovering my mouse above the `Panels`, different `ComboBoxes` were displayed. However, after some seemingly random time, their index will change to 0, displaying the item at said `index`.

Now, I only change the `selectedIndex` of the `ComboBox` in one place in my code, and that spot should not be executed during the test - and it is not, proven by placing a breakpoint that never triggers.

I can change the `selectedIndex` as the user using the `ComboBox` - but I don't do that, so that's out. I just hover over the `Panels`.

I managed to pause the program after it happened to examine the state of the altered `ComboBox`. `SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex` and `Text` properties were all changed. The interesting part? `SelectedIndexChanged` event never fired.

I don't think this has to do anything with the code, but is some kind of strange behaviour of `ComboBox`.

What are the reasons for which the ComboBox might default to first index as selected one, not firing the `SelectedIndexChanged` in the process?

If nothing else, is there a way I could monitor the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox` in a way the code pauses if it changes (as though there was a breakpoint in the setter)?